# How do I post a query string to a form field?

Tags: forms, post

I have a website with a link that says "Click here to claim your prize" and that link goes to a Sales Force catch all web-to-lead form (that multiple sites use and it has a site ID that I append to the URL so the data goes to the right account)

When a user clicks that link and goes to the form page a string (in this case it's the promo code "my prize") needs to be passed to that form page and placed in the comments form field.

My questions are how is this done, are there any tutorials you could point me to, and is there a better method for accomplishing this?

What I'm trying to avoid is having the link say "Click here to win a free prize! Must enter "My Prize" in the comments" and having the user manually enter the promo code.

Thanks muchly in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've used a handy jQuery script in the past called [preset.js](http://www.rainbodesign.com/pub/preset/), although the instructions are not that great it's fairly simple to implement, you may have to pick through his source code though.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be better on stack overflow but I found this blog post which shows example code using `php` and `cURL` to post to the web-to-lead form

http://www.paulwest.co.uk/article.php/salesforce-form-integration-with-php

This is another post about pushing leads to salesforce with php
http://sim.plified.com/2009/02/13/pushing-leads-to-salesforce-with-php/

And one more for good luck

http://www.seobywebmechanix.com/salesforce-php-form-processor-curl-tutorial

Hope these help